# DNN DAL 2 Transactions Accross multiple Repositories

Tags: dotnetnuke, petapoco

I have the following application design

1. Entities (Models)

   - Customer
   - Order
2. Repositories - Wrapper Around the DNN DAL2 Repository for CRUD

   - CustomerRepo
   - OrderRepo

How to implement Transaction support accross multiple repositories

for e.g

```
using(IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance()) {
    ctx.BeginTransaction();


       CustomerRepo.Create(customer);
       order.CustomerID = customer.ID;
       OrderRepo.Create(Order);


    ctx.CommitTransaction();
}
```

CustomerRepo Example.

```
class CustomerRepo
{
    public Customer Create(Customer customer) {
         using(IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance()) 
         {

             var repo = ctx.GetRepository<Customer>();
             repo.Insert(customer);

         }
         return customer;
     }
}
```

Comment: Struggling with the same thing, the documentation for PetaPoco is not helpful at all for dealing with real world complex types.

Comment: I tried to Handle it by using Unitofwork design pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
using(IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
{
    var customerRepo = ctx.GetRepository<Customer>();
    var orderRepo = ctx.GetRepository<Order>();

    ctx.BeginTransaction(); 
    customerRepo.Insert(customer);

    order.CustomerID = customer.ID;

    orderRepo.Insert(order);
    ctx.Commit();
}
```